# What does the notation for a group ${A_n}^*$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

I was on a [website](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/) that catalouges lattices. I was looking through the alternating group lattices and the dihedral lattices and there were two kinds for each. For example, there was $A_2$ and ${A_2}^*$ as well as $D_3$ and ${D_3}^*$.

I can't seem to find any info on what these other groups are. What does that $^*$ indicate?

Comment: Doesn't $*$ just denote the dual lattice? (At least that's what I'd expect without looking at the website.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'*' indicates dual or weighted lattices. See [this pdf](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/latt/lattices.pdf). But, to fulfill this answer, I may assure you that $A_n\;^*$ means the lattice of vectors having integral inner
products with all vectors in $A_n:A_n\;^*=\{x\in R^n |(x,r)\in Z \;for\;all\;r\in A_n\}$. And, that,$A_n\;^*\;^*=A_n$.